# how to write grrovy script to rename a folder with name starting with $ sign

Tags: shell, groovy

I require to rename a folder. The folder name starts with $. In groovy , I tried with

`sh 'mv $popy popy'` But it thrown error.

From termainal, I tried, `mv $popy popy` I got the same error. But when I tried `mv '$popy' popy`. it worked. But the same not working in groovy. How can I make it work on groovy.Please help

Comment: some `groovy` code would be nice

Comment: This is the groovy code to run a shell script sh 'mv $popy popy'  @injecteer

Comment: `sh 'mv \'$popy\' popy'`

Comment: looks like jenkins script?try using triple quote

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to escape the '$' sign, which is a special character in Groovy:

```
sh 'mv \$popy popy'
```

Or you can use groovy code to do this:

```
new File("\$popy").renameTo("popy")
```